# Javascript getUserMedia exclusively microphone input without internal audio

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

My goal is to play sound through speakers and analyze the audio coming in from the speakers. However, when I run `getUserMedia` for the audio input, I'm getting the microphone input AND the audio that is being sent out to the speakers.

I've tested this in as many ways as I can think. I'm hoping that theres some option that I'm missing that makes this possible.

There's [code all over the place for getting microphone input such as this one](http://apprentice.craic.com/tutorials/36) which leads to [this demo](http://web-apprentice-demo.craic.com/tutorials?tutorial=36&demo=1).

When I play [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUvlamJN3nM) or any music from in my computer, it shows up in the audio input stream even if I have headphones on. Thus, the problem is that I cannot get exclusively microphone input...

Any ideas how to make this happen?

Comment: there's no "recording mixer" functionality, at least not yet. they are adding multi-camera support via an in-browser icon interface, like used for some permissions (eg registerPrototcolHandler), so maybe they will add audio source selection as well. one can hope...

Comment: Generally what you get is the default input stream for whatever sound hardware you have. Usually this is just the microphone input, but it's up to the sound card drivers and the OS. You might be able to change it from an OS control panel. What OS are you using? And what browser(s)?

Comment: I'm using Chrome with OSX Yosemite. However, I think I've found the problem and now I feel stupid -- I was using my headphones and the audio was bleeding into the microphone on the headphones! So, apparently it is exclusively the microphone...